# Android: EACCES (Permission denied) , while I added the uses-permisson in manifest

Tags: android

I'm using a very simple code to download an Image from my localhost : here it is :

```
       package com.pep.www.imagedownloader;

       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.util.Log;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import java.io.File;
       import java.io.FileOutputStream;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStream;
       import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
       import java.net.MalformedURLException;
       import java.net.URL;


       public class MainActivity extends Activity {

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

               Button btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
               btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               download();
                           }
                       });
                       thread.start();
                   }
               });
           }


           public void download(){

               int read = -1;
               byte[] buffer = new byte[5*1024];
               URL url = null;
               HttpURLConnection ucon = null;
               InputStream inputStream = null;
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
               File file = null;
               try {
                   url = new URL("http://192.168.1.128/image.jpg");
                   ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   inputStream = ucon.getInputStream();

                   file = new File("mnt/sdcard/image.jpg");
                   fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                   while((read=inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1){
                       fileOutputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
                       Log.i("LOG","Downling : "+read);
                   }
                   Log.i("LOG","Downloaded");
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
```

While I've added this permission in manifest :

```
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I still get this error :

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: mnt/sdcard/image.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

EDIT :

when I change my file path to this :

```
    file = new    File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/image.jpg ");
```

I still get this error :

```
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Pictures/aylar.jpg : open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

EDIT : 
Instead of being so childish and giving downVotes , solve the problem !
Stackoverflow has become a place to play childish games :(

Comment: post your logcat and manifest file

Comment: can you put all your permissions here?

Comment: mnt/sdcard/image.jpg This is a wrong path

Comment: you also need to call `file.createNewFile();` before passing file to `FileOutputStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
file =new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/image.jpg ");
    if(!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: I used you method : 
here is the error : "java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: debug your code, and check on which line you are getting error?

Comment: on line : file.createNewFile();
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: before a min u said java.IOException, now you are telling there is ErrnoException

Comment: logcat shows both errors , believe me , I'me not making this errors myself

Comment: I tried : FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-284
    Process: com.pep.www.imagedownloader, PID: 4128
    java.lang.NullPointerException: file == null

Comment: That error means your if statement is not true ! and file remains null!

Comment: it means you are not having sdcard in your emulator. SDcard is not mounted, try it with emulator having sdcard, or try with real device

Answer (score 2):

Firstly let me tell you one thing If you are using an emulator then the code will not work you need a real device.As we know we give permission to store image in external storage So You can use this method to save your image and then get back.

```
   URL url = new URL ("file://some/path/anImage.png");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
try {
    //The sdcard directory e.g. '/sdcard' can be used directly, or 
    //more safely abstracted with getExternalStorageDirectory()
    File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (new File(storagePath,"myImage.png"));
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: What is this , how can I use this :(?

Comment: Please make sure you have a real device and not testing on emulator because if you use emulator none of the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
file = new File("mnt/sdcard/image.jpg");
```

with

```
file = new File("file:///sdcard/image.jpg");
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/sdcard/image.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory

Comment: then try by put your all permissions after <application>....</application> in your manifest file

like 






<application>
  ...
</application> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 0):

its simple code any file like image,video,audio etc we can download it.

```
Button start;
    //String HttpMyUrl="http://am.cdnmob.org/_/img/loader-small.gif";
    String HttpMyUrl="http://ringtones.mob.org/ringtone/RIusrm-7xATkRQlLw1o89w/1424909358/fa1b23bb5e35c8aed96b1a5aba43df3d/stefano_gambarelli_feat_pochill-land_on_mars_v2.mp3";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       start= (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(HttpMyUrl));
                request.setTitle("File Download");
                request.setDescription("File is being Downloaded...");
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(HttpMyUrl,null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(HttpMyUrl));
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);
                DownloadManager manager =(DownloadManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }


        });
```